# Function of ' | ' in sqlplus query

Tags: sqlplus

Can somebody tell me what the meaning of the vertical bar  ' | ' is in the following sqlplus query?

```
select distinct z303_id_1 Barcode, ' | ', substr(z303_name,1,35) Name from z36, z303
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone just wanted a column with `|` characters in it. That query will return three columns:

- `Barcode` containing the value of `z303_id_1`
- An unnamed column with `|` in it
- `Name` containing the result of `substr(z303_name,1,35)`